# problem with HQL update

Tags: java, hibernate

When I try to execute the following HQL query:

```
Query  query =  getSession().createQuery("update XYZ set status = 10");
query.executeUpdate();
```

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: update
```

EDIT:
I also tried following .But it doennot work either.

```
org.hibernate.Query  query =  getSession().createQuery("update XYZ t set t.status = 10");
```

EDIT2:
Making changes in hinbernate.cfg.xml solved my problem
Earlier i was using

```
setting hibernate.query.factory_class"   = org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactor
```

Now am using following property

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

Comment: Have a look at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=944696&highlight=query+begin+select+delete

Comment: It looks like bulk updates [are indeed permitted](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct), so your question is very interesting.

Comment: Close the quotes in the createQuery. (No related with the problem)

Comment: @ALL: the problem was due to some hibernate propery as mentioned in my edit 2.Why was it so?can somone clarify?

Answer (score 5):

Thats not an HQL query.
You want to import `javax.persistence.Query` which allows *normal* sql,
not `org.hibernate.Query` which works on [entity objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying).

If you want to use simple sql, you could also use [PreparedStatement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

However, if you really want to use hibernate, without taking advantage of entityobjects (totally defeating the point of using hibernate in the first place, imho) you could do it like this ([reference docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct)):

```
String myUpdate = "update XYZ myAlias set myAlias.status = :newStatus";
// or String noAliasMyUpdate = "update XYZ set status = :newStatus";
int updatedEntities = getSession().createQuery(myUpdate) //or noAliasMyUpdate
        .setInt( "newStatus", 10 )
        .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Good one.  I'd go with createSQLQuery for this one also.

Comment: +1, although I disagree with you about defeating the point of using Hibernate. In my opinion sometimes you just must do some bulk operations. And placing the Named query in the appropriate file will prevent the Hibernate to start if the Object change. So you will fix it. Rather than forgetting about bulk updates until you execute them.

Comment: @Udo Fholl True, but this is just a simple update - not a bulk operation.  I got the impression NamedQueries are out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Nimchimpsky:I tried with  your approach as mentioned in my lastest edit , but it doesnot work.

Comment: @akshay, in your question you have listed a different query to the one I have typed

Comment: @ALL: the problem was due to some hibernate propery as mentioned in my edit 2.Why was it so?can somone clarify?

Answer (score 3):

The question is thinking in SQL, when you should be thinking in objects:

```
XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
xyz.setStatus(10);
getSession().merge(xyz);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Query  query =  getSession().createQuery("update XYZ o set o.status = 10");
query.executeUpdate();
```

Take a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct) also.

Comment: does that actually work, I thought you had to supply the named parameter, then set that ?

Comment: You must add the parameter if  there is a named parameter.

Comment: @all: I tried with your approach as mentioned in my lastest edit , but it doesnot work

Answer (score 0):

```
Session sesssion = getSession(); //getter for session
```

For HQL :

```
String hql = "update Activity " +
"set startedOn = :taskStartedOn " +
"where id = :taskId";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setDate("taskStartedOn",new Date());
query.setLong("taskId",1)
int rowCount = query.executeUpdate();
```

Here Activity is POJO.

Comment: There is no reference to Activity as a pojo here; I find this confusing.   And you have to supply the named parameter, then set that using hibernate ?

Comment: Activity is the name of my POJO and yes, It has named parameter "taskstartedOn" and "taskId" also. "startedOn" and "id" is the properties of POJO.

Comment: The pojo is not used anywhere in your snippet, the second sql statement does not use a named parameter.

Comment: Ok I have removed second stmt

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
hibernate.query.factory_class = org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file to resolve exception:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: query must begin with SELECT or FROM: update.....
```